# How to save and show elapsed time correctly in datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I want to save elapsed time in a form into sql table 
timer started at form load event and when I click the save button try to save it with

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duration", textBox3.Text);
```

in sql table and  duration column data saved like this: `00:22`
and this absolutely correct for my job 
but in datagridview's duration column time showed like this:`03/16/2015 12:22pm`

Why data in datagridview converted to a full date data instead of original elapsed time?

Comment: What is the type of this `duration` column exactly in your database and in your datagridview? Can we please see more work like your full code and table informations?

Comment: first time it was a float data type but i changed it to nvarchar(255) for better performance in saving data from c# program

Answer (score 1):

*Well*, you didn't give us enough information about your problem but I try my best..

> first time it was a float data type but i changed it to nvarchar(255)
> for better performance in saving data from c# program

Based on your data (which is `00:22`) neither `float` not `nvarchar` are seem the right type in your database.

If this is a *time interval*, [`time` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) can be the right type since it is a time of a day. But this `time` type *can't* hold bigger than `24:00` values. You will get an error when you try to insert it a bigger value.

If this data can be more bigger than `24:00`, I would suggest to parse it to [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) first and save it's [`Ticks` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx) to [`bigint` typed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) column in your database.

Looks like your program takes your `00:22` and parse it to [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) in somehow like `DateTime.Parse("00:22")`, that's why it generates a today's date with parsed time of day as a `DateTime` in your datagridview.

By the way, don't use `AddWithValue` method as a best practice. It *may* unexpected results sometimes. Use [`.Add()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/40959t6x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overloads to specify your [`SqlDbType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) and it's size.

Further reading:

- [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)
- [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: its call duration like me and you talk on phone for 1:22 1 minutes and 22 sec  and i think maximum call duration is not bigger than 12:59:59  so i try .add () method for save hopefully to save correctly and show correctly in datagridview   thanks a lot for useful information :*

Comment: when i use .Add() method instead of AddwithValues   i have a alert in Error list:   Warning 3 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(string, object)' is obsolete: '"Add(String parameterName, Object value) has been deprecated.  Use AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value).

Comment: @hamed2011 Yes, `SqlParameterCollection.Add(string, object)` method is obsolote. Use [`SqlParameterCollection.Add(string, SqlDbType, Int32)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/40959t6x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead which you can explicitly define your `SqlDbType` and it's size. Don't listen to MSDN in that case. `AddWithValue` might be dangerous.